# find most recent date when value was higher/lower than current in group

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with grouping column (`gr`), date (`c`) (d1 - means current day, d6 - six days ago) and value column (`v`). For every group, I want to find the most recent date when value was lower (or higher) than current value in expanding way.

Here is toy-example with solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import operator
from functools import partial


df0 = pd.DataFrame({
    'gr': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 
    'c': ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6'], 
    'v': [30, 10, 20, 5, 35, 5]
    })


def last_time_op(df, col, t, op):
    #col - column with values
    #t - column with date
    #op eg. operator.gt for lower, lt for higher
    value = df[col]
    series = [op(value.loc[x], value.loc[x+1:]) for x in value.index]
    seriesIndex = [x.where(x==True).first_valid_index() for x in series]
    r = df[t].reindex(seriesIndex)
    return r

df0['dateLower'] = df0.groupby('gr').apply(partial(last_time_op, col='v', t='c', op=operator.gt)).reset_index(drop=True)

df0['dateHigher'] = df0.groupby('gr').apply(partial(last_time_op, col='v', t='c', op=operator.lt)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The result is:

```
  gr   c   v dateLower dateHigher
0  a  d1  30        d2        NaN
1  a  d2  10        d4         d3
2  a  d3  20        d4        NaN
3  a  d4   5       NaN        NaN
4  b  d5  35        d6        NaN
5  b  d6   5       NaN        NaN
```

For example: 10 (row 1, c: d2) < 20 (row 2: c: d3), so `dateHigher` for row 1 is d3.

For higher you need to give `operator.lt` instead of `operator.gt`. Function `last_time_op` works fine also when there is no group-by, but when there is no real-grouping e.g.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'gr': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], #pseudo-grouping
    'c': ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6'], #d1 now #d6 - six days ago
    'v': [30, 10, 20, 5, 35, 5]
    })
```

Then you need to additionally `unstack()` to "coerce shapes":

```
df1['dateLower'] = df1.groupby('gr').apply(partial(last_time_op, col='v', t='c', op=operator.gt)).unstack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Of course, I can find number of unique values in grouping and with `if` provide implementation that is ready for pseudo-grouping, but it looks ugly to me.

Also my function `last_time_op` is not so simple...

I wonder if cleaner, less verbose and more idiomatic approach exists either using pure pandas or some pandas extension?

Solution should be ready mulitple columns in grouping and date-time in `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do cartesian product within each group, then filter out those rows where `c` values on the right are not higher than those on the left (`c < c_`: e.g. we only want to compare `d3` to `[d4, d5, d6]`)

What remains is to find the lowest `c_` where the value on the left `v` is lower/higher than the value on the right `v_`.

Something like this:

```
z = df0.merge(df0, on='gr', suffixes=['', '_']).query('c < c_')

df0.set_index(['gr', 'c']).assign(
    dateLower=z[z['v'].gt(z['v_'])].groupby(['gr', 'c'])['c_'].min(),
    dateHigher=z[z['v'].lt(z['v_'])].groupby(['gr', 'c'])['c_'].min()
).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  gr   c   v dateLower dateHigher
0  a  d1  30        d2        NaN
1  a  d2  10        d4         d3
2  a  d3  20        d4        NaN
3  a  d4   5       NaN        NaN
4  b  d5  35        d6        NaN
5  b  d6   5       NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Really inspiring approach. The only problem I can see - memory consumption of cartesian product for big dataframes.

Comment: @QuantChristo It's true, but the good thing is that you only need to take cartesian product *within groups*, which allows you to split it into smaller dataframes, run it for those chunks, and then concatenate the results (e.g. on the provided sample, I would get the same results running it for `gr` 'a' and 'b' separately, then concatenating the results)